# Cross-platform install of npm package sqlite3

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-platform, travis-ci, node-sqlite3

#### Question

Is there a way to install `node-sqlite3` for multiple platforms I am targeting in my app without running standalone build for just every target platform combination?

#### Context

In my Node.js app I have a npm dependency `node-sqlite3` ([GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)), which contains different binaries (bindings) for different platforms.

My app is targeting different platforms, including **Windows**, **Linux** and **macOS** (both **ia32** and **x64**) and modern Node versions: v6, v7 and v8. The app doesn't have any platform-specific behavior.

If I install the project's dependencies using `npm install`, `node-sqlite3` downloads binaries just for the current platform (let's say `win32`, `x64`, `Node v7.10`).

I also have a Travis CI build configuration, which I use for Continuous Deployment as well as Continuous Integration. I chose [Ubuntu Trusty](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/trusty/) as a host for executing builds.

As a part of a build process the app's dependencies are being installed by `npm install`. Within deployment process, the built app with it's dependencies is being packaged (archived) and uploaded to a file hosting for further distribution.

#### Issue

`node-sqlite3` is not installed for all target platforms I need, but just for a platform currently being used (for development or executing a build).

#### Possible solution

I could execute builds and deploy:

- with Travis - for Linux and macOS
- with AppVeyor - for Windows

But that's looks like a big overhead. As I've already said, the app doesn't have any platform-specific behavior. And I trust `node-sqlite3`'s vendor tested it at all major platforms I am targeting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**, in case with `node-sqlite3` you do have such a capability.

It is possible because it's owner [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox) uses `node-pre-gyp` ([GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp)) for distribution of `node-sqlite3`.

After installing your app's dependencies with `npm install` **execute** the following command at the root of your Node project for **every target platform combination**:

```bash
./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install \
    --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 \
    --target_platform={OS} \
    --target_arch={OS architecture} \
    --target={Node version}
```

As a result, you will have required bindings in the `./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/` directory.

#### Options

Here's the options' descriptions from the [node-pre-gyp docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp#options).

> **--directory**: run the command in this directory

> **--target_platform=win32**: Pass the target platform and override the host platform. Valid values are linux, darwin, win32, sunos, freebsd, openbsd, and aix.

> **--target_arch=ia32**: Pass the target arch and override the host arch. Valid values are 'ia32','x64', or arm.

> **--target=0.10.25**: Pass the target node or node-webkit version to compile against

**If they exist**, prebuilt binaries for chosen platform will be **downloaded** from a file storage (Amazon S3). Otherwise you have to build binaries by yourself.

A list of available binaries of `node-sqlite3` is [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Binaries#available-binaries).

#### Examples

A couple of examples for certain target platforms:

• Windows x86 and Node 6.10.0:

```
./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=win32 --target_arch=ia32 --target=6.10.0
```

• macOS x64 and Node 7.10.0:

```
./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=darwin --target_arch=x64 --target=7.10.0
```

• Linux x64 and Node 8.0.0:

```
./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64 --target=8.0.0
```

Comment: Something that confused me, but I figured out - my error message was talking about missing `lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node`. Even though it says `node-v48` here, you should just use whatever the output is from `node -v` as the argument. In my case it was `6.9.4`

Comment: hi @Deilan, could you please provide the Example for linux armv7

Comment: You can find the node-sqlite3 releases at https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/releases/.

You can then match which version and target parameters you need from your error message, example:
`Error: Cannot find module 'C:\snapshot\modbus\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\node_sqlite3.node'`

To include the windows sqlite3 node within your linux build process you would do:
`/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=win32 --target_arch=x64 --target=16.15.0 --target_libc=unknown`