# How to npm install and compile on travis.ci for multiple environments (including 32 bit)

Tags: github, npm, travis-ci, github-release

I have a project hosted on github that builds and publishes releases to GitHub using Travis.ci:

https://github.com/Roaders/rpi-garage-door/releases/tag/v1.1.0

currently this just adds one tgz file to the release. This includes the bundles dependencies needed to run (the thinking behind this is that `npm install` and `npm run build` are really slow on a raspberry pi so just unzipping a tar is a million times faster). As travis uses 64bit machines the resulting tar files can only be used on 64bit so as part of the upgrade process we need to run `npm rebuild` - which is still fairly slow on RPI 3.

Initially I would like to build a 32 bit version instead of a 64 bit version but I do not know how to configure this on travis. I think I need to change the npm config so I tried this in my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js: 12
script: npm run build-release

before_install:
  npm set npm_config_arch ia32
```

but that doesn't work.

The second thing that I want to do is to build multiple versions of my project using different versions of node and then add all of those tgz files to the release.

this solution:

[Cross-platform install of npm package sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192449/cross-platform-install-of-npm-package-sqlite3)

is very close to what I want but does not work for me as the dependency I need to rebuild (epoll) does not build with `node-pre-gyp`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the other referenced answer was almost there. The difference is that I have to use node-gyp to rebuild `epoll`. I also want to rename the generated tgz file to distinguish between the binaries. These scripts generate the required files for me:

```
"build-release": "npm run build",
"postbuild-release": "npm run build-node10-32 && npm run build-node12-32 && npm run build-node14-32",
"build-node10-32": "npx node-gyp rebuild -C node_modules/epoll/ --arch=arm --target=v10.21.0 && FILENAME=$(npm pack | tail -n 1) && mv $FILENAME \"node_10_32_$FILENAME\"",
"build-node12-32": "npx node-gyp rebuild -C node_modules/epoll/ --arch=arm --target=v12.18.2 && FILENAME=$(npm pack | tail -n 1) && mv $FILENAME \"node_12_32_$FILENAME\"",
"build-node14-32": "npx node-gyp rebuild -C node_modules/epoll/ --arch=arm --target=v14.5.0 && FILENAME=$(npm pack | tail -n 1) && mv $FILENAME \"node_14_32_$FILENAME\"",
```

Note: this doesn't actually solve my specific issue as this still generates 64bit binaries that do not work on my 32 bit raspberry pis. I think the advised fix for this is to use `--arch=ia32` but this results in the error `unrecognized command line option ‘-m32’; did you mean ‘-mbe32’?` but I think fixing that is outside the scope of this question.